# Remote desktop access without client installation or download

Tags: installation, desktop, remote

Is there any solution where user can visit web page for tech support, and tech admin can access his pc to solve problem or perform maintenance. This should be done without any software installation or download on client computer, just clients presence on designated web page.

Comment: Website capable of taking over a computer? I hear these exist at the PwnToOwn competition

Comment: Tools currently available for remote support purposes are good enough, what is stopping you from using them and rather choose this fishy approach ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any remote tech support solution that doesn't require at least *some* downloads. The security risks associated with landing on a website and it automatically giving remote control to a 3rd party is huge.

The options that I have used are as follows:

- [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com) - User lands on a website and has to download and allow a Java package to run. Pros: closest to your requirements. Cons: Lots of dialogs and pop-ups for the user to navigate through.
- [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com) - standalone run once client. Pros: Shortest route for the user with the fewest clicks, also no installation required, can be set to run as a remote system. Cons: the user would have to download the customised client from your website.

In my experience the users prefer not to have lots of extra steps between them getting support and on that basis I would recommend TeamViewer.

Comment: I also recommend team viewer. It requires no installation.